# Spring MVC - Eclipse Warning - Validation Message

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I tried looking for an answer, but kept getting false positives since it's a "Validation Message" warning. I have a jsp with this line

```
<a href="login">Member Home</a>
```

which maps to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(ModelMap model){
    return "home";
}
```

This setup works completely as intended with Spring Security intercepting the request, but I get the warning from Eclipse

```
WebContent/login not found.
```

The warning makes sense, since I don't actually have a file called login, but am I missing a step that prevents the warning.

I also realize that it's just a warning, and I can suck it up, but I really like to avoid that, especially if it leads to bigger problems later.

Using: Spring 3.1.0 and Spring Security 3.1.2 on JBoss 7.1

Edit: More complete warning:

```
Description                 Resource    Path            Location    Type
WebContent/login not found. index.jsp   /RMS/WebContent line 11     Validation Message
```

Line 11 being the html link code I posted above.

Comment: "I get the warning from Eclipse" - Eclipse tells you the source of the message i.e. which plugin's checks are violated. Please post that, too.

Comment: @MarcelStör updated with the complete warning.

Comment: Arggh, bummer...you wrote in your first sentence "it's a "Validation Message" warning" but I didn't get that "Validation Message" is the type, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the type "Validation Message" Eclipse tells you the warning is not coming from any "external" plugin but from Eclipse itself (unless the plugin reports the wrong type). My gut feeling tells me that the source is the 'JSP Content Validator' (Eclipse or project preferences -> Validation). Unfortunately, it can only be switched off/on and not really configured.

Comment: Thanks for the help, you got me in the right section of preferences to find the cause. It was actually the AppXray Validator. I was able to set it to continue to validate XML files, which is helpful, which excluding jsps, which just produce harmless warnings. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Alright, maybe you should have mentioned you're using BEA Workshop Studio (my assumption because of AppXray). Glad you got it fixed.

Comment: I'm running Juno OEPE (Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse), I should have specified, and it slipped my mind that it could have even been something like that.